# Where can I find documentation on the tikzlibrary calc?

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation

Where can I find documentation on the tikzlibrary calc?

Comment: I answered, but I also downvoted because "read the manual" should never be the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In the TikZ manual, section 13.5 in version 2.10.

Comment: And also for version 3.00